# Avoid previously fetched column data in select query by task scheduler

Tags: java, mysql, scheduled-tasks

I have a scheduler that runs every 10 seconds and selects a table from the MySQL database. How can I avoid previously fetched data from the select query?

Answer (score 0):

As you are fetching for every 10 seconds data will inserted or modified within 10 seconds ?

in this case you can use the created date and modified date .

always fetch records created or modified before 10 seconds from the current time.